# How to properly initialize OpenGL in ActiveX controls?

Tags: c++, opengl, activex

I am trying to create a simple ActiveX control using OpenGL. I add some styles in PreCreateWindow:

```
BOOL CMFCActiveXControl1Ctrl::PreCreateWindow(CREATESTRUCT& cs) {
    cs.style |=  WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | WS_CLIPCHILDREN;
    cs.lpszClass = _T("STATIC");
    return COleControl::PreCreateWindow(cs);
}
```

Initialization of OpenGL:

```
int CMFCActiveXControl1Ctrl::OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct) {
    PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd = { 0 };
    pfd.nSize = sizeof(PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR);
    pfd.nVersion = 1;
    pfd.dwFlags = PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW | PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER | PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL;
    pfd.iPixelType = PFD_TYPE_RGBA;
    pfd.cColorBits = 24;
    pfd.cDepthBits = 16;
    pfd.iLayerType = PFD_MAIN_PLANE;
    hDC = ::GetDC(m_hWnd);
    int format = ChoosePixelFormat(hDC, &pfd);
    SetPixelFormat(hDC, format, &pfd);
    hRC = wglCreateContext(hDC);
    wglMakeCurrent(hDC, hRC);
    return 0;
}
```

And then I try to clear color buffer with red color, but all I see is just a black square:

```
void CMFCActiveXControl1Ctrl::OnDraw(
        CDC* pdc, const CRect& rcBounds, const CRect& rcInvalid)
{
    if (!pdc)
       return;
    glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 0);
    SwapBuffers(wglGetCurrentDC());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`glClearColor (...)`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man4/html/glClearColor.xhtml) does not actually clear the color buffer, it just sets the color that will be used when you call [`glClear (...)`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man4/html/glClear.xhtml).

There is a new function in GL3: [`glClearBuffer (...)`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man4/html/glClearBuffer.xhtml) that can be used to clear a buffer to an explicit value all in a single call, but ordinarily you are going to need to call `glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)` after setting the clear color instead.